# How to retrace horizontally merged classes with ProGuard?

Tags: android, proguard

We're using ProGuard to obfuscate and optimize our Android app, and up until now we've kept all class/merging optimizations active. The problem with this is: if an error occurs in a method that was merged horizontally into a different class, the retrace tool does not revert that step, so line numbers become useless and it's impossible to track down the error.

One peculiar example we just had was a static helper method being merged into a class that is part of a 3rd party JAR we link--we don't even have the source code for that. Since retrace shows me line numbers inside that 3rd party class (since the helper method was merged into it), I can't proceed.

Is there any way to retrace methods merged into other classes during optimization?

Answer (score 1):

The standard java class file format doesn't offer a way to represent debug information about different source files ending up in a single class file (although the dalvik format does). ProGuard can therefore merge classes, but not all of their debug information. A line referring to merged classes in a stack trace gets the name of one of these classes. The line number continues to refer to the original source file though, which may be of help.

However, to further complicate things, inlined methods get the line numbers of the invocations. This loss of debug information can also affect the stack traces and their de-obfuscation.

Comment: That's interesting--thanks! Does any of the report files written by ProGuard indicate whether or not a method was inlined? We currently only keep the mapping file under version control so as to reconstruct stack traces for older build tags.

Comment: No, ProGuard doesn't log details about its optimizations. That would be difficult, because optimizations can interact and accumulate in complex ways.